# LED candle flicker circuit

Tags: led, oscillator, pnp

I took apart a flickering LED candle. The circuit oscillates at 1 Hz verified with multimeter and oscilloscope.

[image]

Can anyone explain how the circuit works? It looks like the emitter is grounded in a PNP.

Comment: What are the odds of a schematic error?

Comment: Your schematic wrongly shows a white LED burning out because it is directly connected to a 6V battery. The datasheet for the BSS65 transistor shows a maximum allowed reverse biased emitter-base is only 4V so with the 6V it has avalanche breakdown and conducts, maybe making intermittent noises.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly works similar to one of the "negative resistance" flashing circuits:

http://easy-electronics4u.blogspot.com/2012/02/simplest-led-flasher-one-transistor.html